# When does whitespace matter in Scala?

Tags: scala

When developing in Scala, I seem to frequently run into issues with white space having an unexpected impact on the meaning of the code.

Most recently, I'm having trouble with trying to write a multi-line boolean expression, where breaking the line seems to result in a compile error, i.e.

```
(oneVeryLongExpression < anotherVeryLongExpression) || ((a == b) && c);
```

...compiles just fine, but, if I'm tempted to split the line because of these very long expressions...

```
(oneVeryLongExpression < anotherVeryLongExpression) 
  || ((a == b) && c);
```

...it doesn't compile, which takes me by surprise.

I have found that I can work around that by adding an additional set of parentheses around the entire expression:

```
((oneVeryLongExpression < anotherVeryLongExpression) 
  || ((a == b) && c));
```

...but I'd still like to understand why Scala needs this hint to ignore the newline.

I also have issues when going the other direction: I occasionally convert a moderately large block of Scala code into a set of single-line code snippets, in order to enter each as a single line into a Scala-based shell that doesn't accept multi-line input.

Here's an example of a for-each that I needed to be able to run in my shell as a single line of input (for those who are curious about what I'm doing, I'm looking through a graph of my software for equality checks where the variable types on either side are of a particular type, to find places where `x.equals(y)` should have been used instead of `x == y`):

```
equalityChecks.foreach { node => {
  var lhsFound = false;
  var rhsFound = false;
  breakable {
    node.inEdges().foreach { edge => {
      if (nodesOfTypeT.contains(edge.originNode())) {
        if (edge.tagged(leftOperand)) {
          lhsFound = true;
        };
        if (e.taggedWith(rightOperand)) {
          rhsFound = true;
        };
        if (lhsFound && rhsFound) {
          doublyReachable.add(n);
          break; /* skip the rest of the edges and process next node */
        };
      }
    }}
  };
}};
```

Note the extra semicolons after the `breakable` block and the three `if` blocks, at least some of these were necessary in order to preserve the meaning of the code when the newlines are removed; without them, it does not compile.

Under what circumstances does a newline have semantic meaning in Scala? How can I tell, before I add or remove a newline, whether it will change the meaning of the code?

Answer (score 5):

`(oneVeryLongExpression < anotherVeryLongExpression)` is a proper expression in scala. When compiler traverses the code and meets this expression and nothing in the same line it reports it as the proper expression. Then the next line `|| ((a == b) && c);` becomes unexpected and generates an error. You are right to use the parenthesis to make the compiler know about multiline expression in this case. You could also leave `||` in the first line to make the first line not valid expression:

```
(oneVeryLongExpression < anotherVeryLongExpression) ||
  ((a == b) && c);
```

Also scala REPL accepts multi-line inputs. Just enter `:paste` command and you can enter anything. Press `ctrl-D` to finish

As for the semicolons, they are rarely needed in scala. I think you ever need them either in for-comprehensions or if you put several separate expressions into one line. In your example `node => ...` composes of three expressions: 
`var lhsFound = false`, `var rhsFound = false` and `breakable {...}` Breakable forms a single big expression but it also is formed from a few if statements, so you need to separate each of them as they are separate expressions. This of course is applied only if you have everything as a single-liner. Still I don't think you should ever have to put those semicolons - just use paste mode in REPL.

I find myself using semicolons only in for-comprehensions or in short pattern matches (usually partial functions) where I want them to be a one-liner

P.S. Semicolon before `}` is always optional as it does not separate the expressions. I believe semicolons in your code in the if's after `= true` and `break` can be removed. All others are correct if you put all this code in one line

Comment: Unfortunately, the shell I'm using isn't the standard Scala REPL, and doesn't currently support `:paste`. Though I might add support for that (and for feeding pasted code to the interpreter in paste mode automatically) in the future.

Comment: Coming from Java, I'm particularly surprised about the need for the semicolons after the braces. What is it that Scala is getting confused about? `if (foo) { doFoo(); } if (bar) { doBar(); }` is unambiguous as a Java one-liner, what does Scala think I'm trying to do if I don't place the semicolon between them?

Comment: Scala's rules are simply different here: `if (foo) { doFoo(); }` is an expression, not a statement (as in Java). So `if (foo) { doFoo(); } if (bar) { doBar(); }` is two expressions in a row, like `2 + 2 2 + 2` (or `(2 + 2) (2 + 2)`, at least, which is no better).

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock Scala braces usage is much superior compared to java. For example you could have: `foldLeft (...) { ... } foldLeft (...) { ...}` which reminds `if (...) {...} if (...) {...}` but is also a single expression. You could even create your own method named `if`. So to sum up: I think this is because in scala you can use `{}` when calling methods and because of infix notation - so you can have very complex structures and it is hard to distinguish `if` calls from these structures for scala

Comment: @Archeg `if` is a Scala keyword, you can't name a method `if`. I think Alexy has it right, the difference is that Scala doesn't have an `if` statement, it instead has an `if` expression; reading up on it, it's more like the ternary operator in Java. It's also quite unclear to me what you mean by "superior".

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock By superior I meant that you can use curly braces instead of parenthesis when calling methods. Java can't do that. I agreed with Alexey, just wanted to add a bit more, maybe my addition was not precise enough.